# Get the bounds of the plane visible at a specific z coordinate

Tags: c#, math, opengl, opentk, frustum

Using OpenTK, I've created a window (800x600) with a vertical FOV of 90°. 
I want to make a 2D game with a background image that fits on the whole screen. 
What I want is the plane at a variable z coordinate as a RectangleF.

Currently my code is:

```
var y = (float)(Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4) * z);
return new RectangleF(aspectRatio * -y, -y, 2 * aspectRatio * y, 2 * y);
```

The rectangle calculated by this is always a little to small, this effect seems to decrease with z increasing.
Hoping someone will find my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make a 2D game with a background image that fits on the whole screen.

Then don't bother with perspective calculations. Just switch to an orthographic projection for drawing the background, disabling depth writes. Then switch to a perspective projection for the rest.

OpenGL is not a scene graph, it's a statefull drawing API. Make use of that fact.

Comment: Well, I was actually planning on using the perspective for zoom and maybe some 3D-expansions, so switching to ortho isn't really the best solution. Also I'm more eager to know my mistake than to get a work-around.

Comment: @timedev Using an ortho projection to draw 2D isn't a workaround, it's the correct way of doing things. Even in 3D games 2D overlays are drawn using ortho projections. To zoom, you can change the ortho projection like so - http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/132061-help-with-orthographic-zoom

Comment: @timedev: It's not a workaround. It's the only proper way and the best solution to do this. Never try to overcomplicate things. OpenGL is not a scenegraph. You are *supposed* to switch projections where needed.

Answer (score 0):

To make a 2D game using OpenGL, you should use an orthographic projection, like [this](http://basic4gl.wikispaces.com/2D+Drawing+in+OpenGL) tutorial shows.

Then its simple to fill the screen with whatever image you want because you aren't dealing with perspective.

*However, IF you were to insist on doing things the way you say, then you'd have to [gluProject](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml) the 4 corners of your screen using the current modelview matrix and then draw a quad in 3D space with those corners. Even with this method, it is likely that the quad might not cover the entire screen sometimes due to floating point errors.*